# how to List all chart dependency names from Chart.yaml in NOTES.txt

Tags: kubernetes-helm, helm3

I am currently trying to get all the charts I included in my `Chart.yaml` file where am using a common chart multiple times with different **aliases** so I can reuse it.

the problem is I couldn't find deep documentation about getting some of the Chart values as following the [helm Built-In Objects](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/builtin_objects/) documentation

```yaml
apiVersion: v2
name: example
description: A Helm chart for Kubernetes
type: application
version: 0.1.0
appVersion: "1.16.0"

dependencies:
  - name: common
    version: x.x.x
    alias: app1
  - name: common
    version: x.x.x
    alias: app2
```

In `NOTES.txt` I managed to get interesting information about the dependencies by using this code example:

```yaml
{{ range .Chart.Dependencies }}
{{ . }}
{{- end }}
```

and this is what I am getting as an output:

```sh
{app1 x.x.x   [] true [] app1}
{app2 x.x.x   [] true [] app2}
```

I tried accessing the dependency name using {{ .alias }}, instead am getting this error:

```sh
Error: INSTALLATION FAILED: template: example/templates/NOTES.txt:2:3: executing "example/templates/NOTES.txt" at <.alias>: can't evaluate field alias in type *chart.Dependency
```

How can I extract the aliases/names from that output string?

> Am using helm v3.8.0 and debugging with `helm install project . --dry-run`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to run this by using this code:

```yaml
{{ range .Chart.Dependencies }}
{{ with fromJson (toJson .) }}
{{ .alias }}
{{- end }}
{{- end }}
```

this basically formats the strings to json as string object using `toJson` then read them using `fromJson` which in fact allowed me to read key/value objects.

> Without fromJson you will get this error `at <.alias>: can't evaluate field alias in type string`